# Images in Ioslides Presentation not Properly Converted to Base64 Anymore

Tags: r, base64, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have an ioslides presentation which I create and render in RStudio.
Last week the presentation was properly rendered and everyone was happy. But now I have a problem. I added an image on each slide at the top right corner by modifying the default css style template. More precisely I changed the followng selector:

```
/* line 62, ../scss/default.scss */
slides > slide {
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #797979;
  width: 900px;
  height: 700px;
  margin-left: -450px;
  margin-top: -350px;
  padding: 40px 60px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;

  background-image: url(Images/logodue.png) !important;
  background-size: 200px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: 93.1% 4% !important;
}
```

I added the four background properties at the very end. Note that I added the background image using a relative path and used a *.png file.
I then just include the CSS template in my YAML header:

```
---
title: "My Presentation"
csl: mee.csl
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: dueCSS.css
    widescreen: yes
bibliography: references.bib  
---
```

For some reason, this image is not displayed. Images I added within the presentation file are encoded and shown without problems. Just the logo in the stylesheet wont. When I check the source code of the output HTML slides the stylesheet is included properly and the image seems to be encoded as well:

```
slides > slide {
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #797979;
  .......
  .......
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background-image: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg....AND SO ON
```

I already tried opening it with Chrome and Firefox but none of them shows the logo anymore. Does anyone have an idea?

**EDIT:** Somethin is displayed indeed. But its not the logo. It looks like this (screenshot of the upper right corner of a slide):

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Further investigation shows, that the stylesheet is also encoded  and included in the final HTML file like this:

```
<link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8,%40charset%20%22UTF%2D8%22%3B%0<!-- rest of the base64 code -->" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I change that to the "real" stylesheet it works fine:

```
<link href="dueCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Therefore the error has to be in the knitting procedure I guess?

Comment: Thats not the answer. Thats a way to clean up the mess afterwards.

Comment: For the record: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/550